# Hi All, I am getting an error says - ParserError: Expected ';' but got 'contract' contract Token.If someone can help me that'd be very helpful.Thanks

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

```
Pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract('Token', ([deployer, receiver]) => { 

 const name = 'Arv Token' 
 const symbol = 'ARVV' 
 const decimals = '18' 
 const totalSupply = tokens(1000000).toString() 
 let token

    beforeEach(async () => {
        token = await Token.new()
    })
```

Comment: Please past ethe complete error message to the body not to the question headline.

Comment: pragma instead Pragma

Answer (score 0):

It seems You forgot the semi-columns after your constants and nearly every line of code.

```
const x = 'a constant';
const y = 23445;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are just missing the ';' at the end of your lines.
Try this code.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract('Token', ([deployer, receiver]) => { 

 const name = 'Arv Token';
 const symbol = 'ARVV';
 const decimals = '18';
 const totalSupply = tokens(1000000).toString();
 let token

    beforeEach(async () => {
        token = await Token.new();
    })
```